# How to sort a dictionary in the same order of another dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have two dictionary one composed by:

1) `<Id, Name>`

This dictionaryis sorted by "Name"

Another dictionary composed by:

2) `<Id, ListOfValues>`

This dictionary`is not sorted.

I have to sort the second dictionary in the same order of the first, i can use Id as common point, how i can do this?

How i can sort the second dictionary

```
String json = data as string;
var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SectionItem>>(json);

/* New dictionary used to order item for name */ 
Dictionary<string, string> dataToOrder = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var name ="";
/* Getting data in "local language" */
var local_lang = ConfigurationContext.CurrentLocale;

/* In dataToOrder I insert name and Id*/
foreach (SectionItem si in rawData)
{
      name = si.Entities[local_lang].Name;
      dataToOrder.Add(name, si.Id);
}

/* List with ordered data by name*/
var orderedData = dataToOrder.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

Now I have to order each element of rawdata in the same order of orderedData , how i can do this ?

```
public class SectionItem
{
    public string Id;
    public Dictionary<string, EntityGroup> Entities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort `SecondDictionary` based on *Key* of a `dataToOrder`, you could do this.

Look for an index of seconddiction `Key` in the first dictionary and use for Ordering the dictionary..

```
var ids = dataToOrder.Keys.ToList();

SecondDictionary.OrderBy(x=> ids.Contain(x.Key)? ids.IndexOf(x.Key) : int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: dataToOrder contains a list composed by Id and a name (two string). I have to order rawData, tant contais a list that use as Key the "Id" and as values a SectionItem.

With your solution i solve my problem ?